# How to make auto overflow work on unordered list in fixed div?

Tags: html, css, list, overflow

I have a vertical fixed div on the left of my web page with the purpose of being a side menu, with the main content appearing to its right. The left menu contains an unordered list which may contain many items and it is therefore desirable that when all items cannot be displayed at once (eg. browser window too small), the unordered list section will automatically produce the appropriate scrollbars (not the entire fixed left menu div).

I am unable to achieve the desired effect and don't understand why my code does not work as I am fairly new to HTML and CSS. Your help would be appreciated.

## EDIT

- **Scrollbars should not appear unless required to display content**
- **If the unordered list items are too big/many to display, scrollbars should be produced to scroll only the items section (not whole left menu div or menu title)**
- **The unordered list section should not proceed to the bottom of the page, but only be as large as necessary to display item list**

https://jsfiddle.net/afe102mt/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #cc2900;
}

li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  background-color: #b32400;
  font-family: Arial;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#leftMenu {
  background-color: #cc2900;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}

#pageContent {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  position: absolute;
}

#title {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftMenu">
  <div id="title">Menu title</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#menuItem1">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem2">Menu item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem3">Menu item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem4">Menu item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem5">Menu item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem6">Menu item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem7">Menu item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem8">Menu item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem9">Menu item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem10">Menu item 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem11">Menu item 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem12">Menu item 12</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="pageContent">
  <h1>Page title goes here</h1>
  <br />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mollis venenatis magna vitae rutrum. Aliquam cursus orci ac congue ultricies. Sed nec tempus est. Cras vitae efficitur arcu, eget pulvinar nibh. Vivamus gravida iaculis elit vitae consectetur.
    Aliquam efficitur diam quis rutrum semper. Donec pharetra lacus a tempus lobortis. Ut sit amet ex id nisl sagittis faucibus. Curabitur sed lorem leo.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Phasellus mollis placerat quam eget rutrum. Suspendisse odio nulla, rutrum id mi ac, elementum vehicula nisi. Nam pretium dignissim nunc ac efficitur. Mauris semper nunc eu ligula porta luctus. Quisque pellentesque dignissim fringilla. Morbi tincidunt
    mi quis luctus blandit. Quisque erat dui, vehicula quis porttitor eu, fringilla id erat. Curabitur dapibus dolor et eros fringilla, at mattis metus placerat. In vitae mauris quis eros fringilla rhoncus et et enim. Nunc vestibulum blandit tortor ut
    auctor. Praesent nisi ipsum, posuere et aliquet a, iaculis vel orci. Integer erat tortor, vehicula ut eros quis, condimentum volutpat sapien. Pellentesque id neque vitae sem condimentum dictum. Sed tristique sapien purus, quis iaculis turpis dictum
    vel.
  </p>
  <br />
  <p>Donec sed eros quis mi sagittis varius eget a orci. Nullam sollicitudin sem massa. In laoreet eros eget nulla rutrum, quis sollicitudin tortor mollis. Nulla facilisi. Donec hendrerit tortor vel metus mollis pellentesque. Nulla egestas sagittis rutrum.
    Nulla maximus aliquam magna ullamcorper viverra. Proin molestie mattis tortor eu consequat. Sed eu dolor eget diam vehicula pulvinar ac tempus nisl. Aenean urna sapien, viverra vel arcu at, aliquam fringilla elit.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Nunc tempor enim nec dolor elementum, sed pulvinar lacus accumsan. Pellentesque eu magna et urna tincidunt scelerisque. In eu finibus quam. Praesent egestas, ipsum ac efficitur dictum, tortor urna aliquet augue, nec elementum mi elit sit amet enim.
    Nunc sodales, libero eget convallis fringilla, mi eros bibendum mauris, sit amet eleifend lectus nibh sit amet lectus. Etiam vitae consequat ipsum. Nulla semper, orci quis fermentum gravida, sem neque ultrices tellus, non fringilla augue ex quis augue.
    Aenean vestibulum bibendum diam, at blandit elit cursus.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Praesent bibendum, ligula maximus egestas ullamcorper, felis elit feugiat augue, in pulvinar nulla erat a odio. Vivamus massa enim, mollis et tincidunt eget, faucibus non ex. Suspendisse id tortor ac risus pharetra ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent in nunc a est rhoncus fermentum. Suspendisse id feugiat ligula, vel ultrices arcu. Aenean a dolor neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Vivamus interdum non metus a vulputate. Donec consequat lacus rutrum lectus facilisis pharetra in ac est. Nulla sed massa velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed sit amet lacus id libero
    volutpat fringilla non quis mauris. Morbi viverra mi nec tortor molestie congue. Pellentesque eu sem orci. Sed mattis interdum orci ut ultrices. Vivamus metus nisl, eleifend vitae dapibus venenatis, sagittis at elit.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Integer quis purus maximus, commodo nisi sit amet, ultrices quam. Vivamus vitae elementum tellus, sed ultrices quam. Phasellus tempor risus id sollicitudin accumsan. Etiam sagittis fringilla consectetur. Aenean non dui sapien. Mauris vitae pulvinar
    quam, nec efficitur mauris. Quisque at laoreet justo, at maximus felis. Morbi orci justo, convallis et nisi eget, semper efficitur purus. Phasellus sed porttitor ex. Quisque eget aliquet felis. Quisque ac neque nunc. Etiam sit amet libero orci. Praesent
    mattis fringilla metus, vel pretium odio. Cras quam turpis, luctus ut sagittis eget, placerat pretium odio. Proin sit amet tempus tellus, in bibendum elit.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque pulvinar massa velit, vel rhoncus leo iaculis vel. Vestibulum vestibulum sagittis tellus, eget viverra magna aliquet id. Donec tincidunt
    commodo elit, et sollicitudin tellus placerat ullamcorper. Aenean non aliquet urna. Nam tellus velit, ornare eu egestas laoreet, lobortis sit amet felis. Curabitur pulvinar pretium libero, eu blandit tortor dictum a. Aliquam mollis nisi a metus facilisis
    euismod.
  </p>
  <br />
  <p>Maecenas consectetur vulputate enim non fringilla. Vestibulum a vulputate mi, et aliquet orci. Mauris orci ipsum, interdum malesuada tincidunt eget, auctor lobortis felis. Quisque sed augue sapien. Morbi pretium vitae lacus sit amet feugiat. Vestibulum
    ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed porttitor id ipsum vel condimentum. Praesent porta mattis odio. Vestibulum interdum pellentesque consectetur. Pellentesque vestibulum tellus a erat tempor finibus.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Etiam placerat nisl sit amet ex aliquam, mattis auctor mauris cursus. Mauris feugiat hendrerit suscipit. Curabitur eget condimentum erat. Maecenas auctor ornare orci tincidunt blandit. Etiam non accumsan arcu. Praesent finibus, risus a porttitor sollicitudin,
    felis magna porttitor sem, vitae pretium nunc mi a lectus. Integer auctor auctor felis et posuere.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Ut elementum orci a augue aliquam dapibus. Morbi porta fringilla enim et pulvinar. Praesent sed condimentum enim. Nunc in lacus vitae purus lobortis placerat eu sit amet sem. Curabitur vitae sem commodo, volutpat lorem eu, placerat lacus. Orci varius
    natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac consectetur lorem. Integer nec felis nibh. Etiam ornare luctus justo, in gravida leo. Quisque facilisis risus
    erat, non pulvinar lacus maximus non.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Vestibulum ornare a purus vel aliquet. Suspendisse a gravida dui. Fusce blandit, tellus molestie dignissim aliquam, dui ligula efficitur nunc, maximus molestie neque magna eu arcu. Maecenas convallis ipsum quis dapibus feugiat. Suspendisse vehicula
    consequat molestie. Aliquam venenatis lacus a nunc vestibulum, sed viverra leo fermentum. Nullam accumsan quam vel dolor auctor ultrices. Vivamus id neque et orci rutrum pharetra quis vel orci.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Phasellus et sapien nec eros consequat vulputate. Cras tempor pellentesque fermentum. Sed mattis ipsum sit amet mauris molestie, ac iaculis ligula bibendum. Morbi vitae condimentum nibh. Duis at urna nisi. Phasellus lacinia dolor mi, id euismod mauris
    tempor vel. In ac enim vulputate, egestas magna vitae, porta tortor. Cras pellentesque sapien ac nunc mattis, id laoreet ex pellentesque. Phasellus vel libero eget nisi gravida pharetra sit amet vitae mi. Maecenas a felis vitae mauris interdum blandit
    in nec justo. Integer placerat elit quis orci pellentesque efficitur nec faucibus metus. Ut fermentum arcu et nisl vehicula</p>
  <br />
  <p>Nulla finibus ante in convallis iaculis. Donec ac vulputate nulla. Aliquam venenatis sem et turpis fermentum, vel iaculis ex fermentum. Mauris blandit, odio vitae ultricies bibendum, ligula justo imperdiet nisi, vel rhoncus leo felis ac sem. Vivamus
    id egestas purus, sed mattis diam. Mauris cursus eget augue nec pretium. Integer mollis, nisl quis lobortis facilisis, libero dui pulvinar urna, quis fermentum massa nulla vel felis. Vivamus blandit facilisis tortor non dictum. Phasellus dapibus sapien
    ultricies sodales aliquam. Fusce ac dui posuere, varius magna et, faucibus justo. Nulla accumsan nunc elementum sollicitudin malesuada.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Suspendisse tristique, mauris at auctor bibendum, ante massa interdum erat, et scelerisque ipsum metus vel odio. Sed malesuada, augue ac volutpat ullamcorper, turpis ipsum consequat mi, sed pharetra dui est sed tellus. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur
    mollis, enim condimentum tempus sagittis, ligula ex dapibus purus, ac cursus lacus diam quis erat. Nulla et mi a lacus semper gravida. Aliquam libero orci, efficitur nec luctus quis, sagittis sit amet tortor. Donec ac ligula quis elit dignissim venenatis.
    Duis ut arcu auctor lorem molestie tristique vitae id orci. Praesent venenatis turpis in tortor viverra dignissim. Sed at blandit neque. Pellentesque nisi ipsum, aliquam in leo ut, commodo iaculis leo. Praesent sodales tristique tellus eget tempor.
    Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Nulla sit amet enim euismod, rhoncus purus elementum, venenatis libero. Pellentesque vitae eros sit amet purus tincidunt pharetra vitae ac enim. Phasellus nisi odio, vulputate sed posuere nec, consequat et lacus. Suspendisse in tortor a nulla pellentesque
    consectetur in eu lorem. Etiam elit turpis, sagittis id sapien et, tempor facilisis leo. Donec malesuada nibh quis sollicitudin mattis. Curabitur cursus massa faucibus leo molestie cursus. Etiam dictum ultricies tortor eu vestibulum. Donec tincidunt
    nunc in tortor luctus, at varius erat dignissim.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Ut porta eros at nibh ultrices, aliquet imperdiet nisi tempus. Nulla lobortis nec massa vel rhoncus. Proin posuere quam nec nulla viverra hendrerit. Donec eget ex non nisi faucibus finibus. Ut porta sollicitudin ante a convallis. Pellentesque eleifend
    elementum malesuada. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam risus lacus, placerat vitae velit non, convallis venenatis diam. Suspendisse non neque sem. Nam ultricies nisi tincidunt nisl tristique interdum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nunc purus, luctus sed
    mi ac, fringilla efficitur sapien. Nunc lacinia rutrum est suscipit molestie. Cras tempus velit quam, euismod venenatis eros gravida.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Donec purus augue, cursus vel suscipit eget, cursus eu tortor. Pellentesque sit amet libero justo. Nulla tempus urna nisl, a consectetur tellus ultricies at. Vivamus eget viverra est. Sed facilisis, libero quis varius scelerisque, odio mi volutpat nisi,
    finibus ullamcorper ex nibh euismod ante. Aenean quis elit felis. Aenean tincidunt scelerisque neque nec porta. Morbi vitae justo a leo sagittis ultricies. Sed sed arcu nulla. Duis consequat metus in placerat convallis. Cras rutrum pretium est sed
    malesuada. In id erat vestibulum, imperdiet enim placerat, eleifend felis. Cras egestas erat a mauris ultricies rhoncus. Curabitur blandit porta vulputate. In lobortis porttitor velit.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it to work two ways, using flex or calc for height.
When I would have to explain why it doesn't work for you and why it works now I would say that setting ul position to absolute makes it unresponsive to page height change as it has no height. It starts to be responsive when it has relative height set. Flex makes it take full remaining height, and calc allows to subtract menu header height so it takes remaining height.

With flex (changes are in #leftMenu and ul):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #cc2900;
}

li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  background-color: #b32400;
  font-family: Arial;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#leftMenu {
  background-color: #cc2900;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#pageContent {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  position: absolute;
}

#title {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>repl.it</title>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="leftMenu">
  <div id="title">Menu title</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#menuItem1">Menu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem2">Menu item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem3">Menu item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem4">Menu item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem5">Menu item 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem6">Menu item 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem7">Menu item 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem8">Menu item 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem9">Menu item 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem10">Menu item 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem11">Menu item 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem12">Menu item 12</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="pageContent">
  <h1>Page title goes here</h1>
  <br />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mollis venenatis magna vitae rutrum. Aliquam cursus orci ac congue ultricies. Sed nec tempus est. Cras vitae efficitur arcu, eget pulvinar nibh. Vivamus gravida iaculis elit vitae consectetur.
    Aliquam efficitur diam quis rutrum semper. Donec pharetra lacus a tempus lobortis. Ut sit amet ex id nisl sagittis faucibus. Curabitur sed lorem leo.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Phasellus mollis placerat quam eget rutrum. Suspendisse odio nulla, rutrum id mi ac, elementum vehicula nisi. Nam pretium dignissim nunc ac efficitur. Mauris semper nunc eu ligula porta luctus. Quisque pellentesque dignissim fringilla. Morbi tincidunt
    mi quis luctus blandit. Quisque erat dui, vehicula quis porttitor eu, fringilla id erat. Curabitur dapibus dolor et eros fringilla, at mattis metus placerat. In vitae mauris quis eros fringilla rhoncus et et enim. Nunc vestibulum blandit tortor ut
    auctor. Praesent nisi ipsum, posuere et aliquet a, iaculis vel orci. Integer erat tortor, vehicula ut eros quis, condimentum volutpat sapien. Pellentesque id neque vitae sem condimentum dictum. Sed tristique sapien purus, quis iaculis turpis dictum
    vel.
  </p>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

With calc (changes are in ul):
I calculate 100% height for ul and subtract 66px of menu header height

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #cc2900;
}

li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  background-color: #b32400;
  font-family: Arial;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 66px);
}

#leftMenu {
  background-color: #cc2900;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}

#pageContent {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  position: absolute;
}

#title {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>repl.it</title>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="leftMenu">
  <div id="title">Menu title</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#menuItem1">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem2">Menu item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem3">Menu item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem4">Menu item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem5">Menu item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem6">Menu item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem7">Menu item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem8">Menu item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem9">Menu item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem10">Menu item 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem11">Menu item 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menuItem12">Menu item 12</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="pageContent">
  <h1>Page title goes here</h1>
  <br />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mollis venenatis magna vitae rutrum. Aliquam cursus orci ac congue ultricies. Sed nec tempus est. Cras vitae efficitur arcu, eget pulvinar nibh. Vivamus gravida iaculis elit vitae consectetur.
    Aliquam efficitur diam quis rutrum semper. Donec pharetra lacus a tempus lobortis. Ut sit amet ex id nisl sagittis faucibus. Curabitur sed lorem leo.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Phasellus mollis placerat quam eget rutrum. Suspendisse odio nulla, rutrum id mi ac, elementum vehicula nisi. Nam pretium dignissim nunc ac efficitur. Mauris semper nunc eu ligula porta luctus. Quisque pellentesque dignissim fringilla. Morbi tincidunt
    mi quis luctus blandit. Quisque erat dui, vehicula quis porttitor eu, fringilla id erat. Curabitur dapibus dolor et eros fringilla, at mattis metus placerat. In vitae mauris quis eros fringilla rhoncus et et enim. Nunc vestibulum blandit tortor ut
    auctor. Praesent nisi ipsum, posuere et aliquet a, iaculis vel orci. Integer erat tortor, vehicula ut eros quis, condimentum volutpat sapien. Pellentesque id neque vitae sem condimentum dictum. Sed tristique sapien purus, quis iaculis turpis dictum
    vel.
  </p>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**
I figured out a third option which is leaving ul to be positioned absolutely, but hiving it some height by setting bottom to 0 and top to 66px to compensate menu header:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #cc2900;
}

li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  background-color: #b32400;
  font-family: Arial;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#leftMenu {
  background-color: #cc2900;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}

#pageContent {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  position: absolute;
}

#title {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>repl.it</title>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="leftMenu">
  <div id="title">Menu title</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#menuItem1">Menu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem2">Menu item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem3">Menu item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem4">Menu item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem5">Menu item 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem6">Menu item 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem7">Menu item 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem8">Menu item 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem9">Menu item 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem10">Menu item 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem11">Menu item 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuItem12">Menu item 12</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="pageContent">
  <h1>Page title goes here</h1>
  <br />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mollis venenatis magna vitae rutrum. Aliquam cursus orci ac congue ultricies. Sed nec tempus est. Cras vitae efficitur arcu, eget pulvinar nibh. Vivamus gravida iaculis elit vitae consectetur.
    Aliquam efficitur diam quis rutrum semper. Donec pharetra lacus a tempus lobortis. Ut sit amet ex id nisl sagittis faucibus. Curabitur sed lorem leo.</p>
  <br />
  <p>Phasellus mollis placerat quam eget rutrum. Suspendisse odio nulla, rutrum id mi ac, elementum vehicula nisi. Nam pretium dignissim nunc ac efficitur. Mauris semper nunc eu ligula porta luctus. Quisque pellentesque dignissim fringilla. Morbi tincidunt
    mi quis luctus blandit. Quisque erat dui, vehicula quis porttitor eu, fringilla id erat. Curabitur dapibus dolor et eros fringilla, at mattis metus placerat. In vitae mauris quis eros fringilla rhoncus et et enim. Nunc vestibulum blandit tortor ut
    auctor. Praesent nisi ipsum, posuere et aliquet a, iaculis vel orci. Integer erat tortor, vehicula ut eros quis, condimentum volutpat sapien. Pellentesque id neque vitae sem condimentum dictum. Sed tristique sapien purus, quis iaculis turpis dictum
    vel.
  </p>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, your first solution works well. I did however change the height property for the unordered list to max-height: 100% to prevent the unordered list background colour continuing further than the space occupied by items.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the overflow property of the left menu

```
    #leftMenu {
      background-color: #cc2900;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: scroll;
      position: fixed;  
      width: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this results in the entire left menu scrolling (including menu title) which is not desired, and that a scrollbar always appears even when unneeded.

Comment: He could change the `overflow:scroll` to `overflow:auto` which would serve the same purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }

  ul > li + li {
      border-top: 1px solid #cc2900;
  }

  li a {
      color: #000;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 8px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  li a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
  }

  #title {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 36px;
      padding: 12px;
      text-align: center;
  }

  li a:hover:not(.active) {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
  }

  ul {
      background-color: #b32400;
      font-family: Arial;
      list-style: none;
      overflow-y:scroll;
      position: absolute;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      width: 200px;
      height:100%;
  }

  #leftMenu {
      background-color: #cc2900;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      width: 200px;
  }

  #pageContent {
      margin-left: 200px;
      padding: 2% 3%;
      position: absolute;
  }
```

**P.S:** Replace your entire CSS with this.
Please let me know if this works.

Re-post:

```
    ul {
        background-color: #b32400;
        font-family: Arial;
        list-style: none;
        overflow-y:auto;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        max-height:100%;  
   }

   #leftMenu {
        background-color: #cc2900;
        height:100%;
        position: fixed;
        width: 200px;
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this results in a scrollbar always being present. I would like the scrollbar to only appear if the browser does not have the vertical space to display all menu items. It also results in the unordered list continuing to the bottom of the page unnecessarily, whereas it should only consume as much space as may be needed by its items.

Comment: Please check the code inserted in my answer under the **Re-post** heading

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css try your code add some menu and delete and check it.

## leftMenu{overflow-y:auto;}